# Multiple AWS EC2 Instance with Single Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scalability

Currently we are using One EC2 instance to run our Services. And we are planning to add one more instance to put our application Server. Is it better to put the database in separate instance and query from both instances or is there any better solution?
Meanwhile we also have to consider about the scalability when we want to add more servers at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is basically the same inside or outside of EC2.

Without hearing more about the specifics of your architecture and application requirements, I would  default to recommending that MySQL be put on its own server.

Here's a good writeup on some of the issues to consider:

> http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/10/16/should-mysql-and-web-server-share-the-same-box/

Comment: Thanks for the link.Finally we used separate ebs backed ec2 instance(currently m1.small) to run database.Our requirement is to have a high availability solution provided with two clustered Liferay servers as Application server running in two separate EBS backed instance. And separate database storage for scalability issue. We are using ELB, which loadbalances two App Server. Can anybody share their experience regarding the liferay clustering under Amazon AWS?
Thanks